# How to customize MFMailComposeViewController so that i can make the "to" field as non-editable?

Tags: iphone, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, feedback

I am using MFMailComposeViewController for sending feedback in my app. It works fine. But the problem here is, the user can edit/delete the "to" address. I want to make it as a non-editable one. May be, the user can add some mail addresses in "to" field.

But he/she should not delete the feedback address (Here, it is "support@xxxx.com").

Here is my code...

```
MFMailComposeViewController *composeWindow = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
composeWindow.mailComposeDelegate = self;

NSString *str = @"Subject of the feedback";
[composeWindow setSubject:[str stringByAppendingString:[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]]];

NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"support@xxxx.com"]; 
[composeWindow setToRecipients:toRecipients];

[self presentModalViewController:composeWindow animated:YES];
[composeWindow release];
```

Thanks in Advance

Rajkanth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not customize `MFMailComposeViewController` to avoid editing. Apple forbids this, and the reason is quite simple: it is the user and not you that must decide exactly what to send, to whom etc. The same applies for the UI controller allowing to send SMS (text) messages. And, of course, Apple does not allows sending an email or SMS without explicit interaction with the user. It is the user that must validate and send the email or SMS message. The validation process include the ability to cancel the message or to change any single property at will, including the "to" recipients.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. I understood that before submitting our interface we should set the values. The user can modify/delete them as they want. But see, i used this controller ONLY for submitting the feedback about my application. I am not providing a mail service in my app!!! Maybe, they want to send the feedback's copy to some person. But if they use this feedback option, i should get the mail. I don't know why apple do this manner!! Anyway, thank you so much...

Answer (score 6):

All the other answers are correct. You can not change the interface of the MFMailComposeViewController. But you have other possibilities. ;-)

[Three20 SDK](https://github.com/facebook/three20) includes also an Mail Composer. Try it out. I think it should be that far changeable, that the "to" field is not editable anymore.

I hope my answer is helpful for you.

Sandro Meier

**EDIT**

Three20 SDK was discontinued a while ago. So you shouldn't use it anymore for new projects. I advise you to use [NimbusKit](http://nimbuskit.info) instead. This is also recommended by the Three20 SDK team. Sadly it does not include a MailComposeViewController

Answer (score 3):

From the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Important: The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application. In addition, after presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make further changes to the email content. The user may still edit the content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored. Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the interface.