# add button inside the MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have created a functionality to send sms from my app using MFMessageComposeViewController.

In that i want to add button named "Templates" inside the MFMessageComposeViewController. when cliking on that button i want to push a view.

Is that possible ...please help me out

Answer (score 0):

No u cannot customize the mail composer for explanation go through the answer at this link [How to customize MFMailComposeViewController so that i can make the "to" field as non-editable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049270/how-to-customize-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-so-that-i-can-make-the-to-field-a)