# How to customize a message compose screen in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, email, message

Now i'm working in iPhone application, Using Label to set a text like (To:), Textfield for enter the text or number and add a plus button for add a contacts.
When i entered the name in textfield then press a plus button, the contact name display in the textfield but the background image are not visible in the textfield like below i mentioned the picture, Field To: (yuvaraj) contact background image is lightblue.
please any one help me.

Thanks in Advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not customize MFMailComposeViewController to avoid editing. Apple forbids this, and the reason is quite simple: it is the user and not you that must decide exactly what to send, to whom etc. The same applies for the UI controller allowing to send SMS (text) messages. And, of course, Apple does not allows sending an email or SMS without explicit interaction with the user. It is the user that must validate and send the email or SMS message. The validation process include the ability to cancel the message or to change any single property at will, including the "to" recipients.  from [How to customize MFMailComposeViewController so that i can make the "to" field as non-editable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049270/how-to-customize-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-so-that-i-can-make-the-to-field-a) However you can try with this link http://sugartin.info/2011/10/13/sending-a-mail-useing-gmail/