# convert nsstring into pdf format then send mail

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, pdf, mfmailcomposer

```
-(void)sendmail
{
MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];


[mailer setSubject:@"iOS School - MultipleAlertViews"];

NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil];
[mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

NSString *        [emailBody appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<hr> <font face=\"verdana\" size=\"2\" color=\"black\"> <table width=\"700px\" border=\"1px;\"><tr><td width=\"200px\"><img src='%@' width=\"200\" height=\"200\"></td><td width=\"500px\"> <b>&nbsp%@/%@/%@ &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Price: %@%@ </b></br><hr>&nbsp %@ </br><hr></br><hr>&nbsp Gross Wt: %0.2f gms &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp  Net Wt.: %@ gms </br><hr>&nbsp Dia: %d/%0.2f cts &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Col.Stone: %d/%0.2f cts</td></tr></table></font>",



[mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

[self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
}
```

here emailBody is convert into pdf then sent mail, here i don't want to edit anything, or disable the keypad.

Comment: Don't you need to use `[MFMailComposeViewController addAttachmentData]`?

Comment: you want to send pdf file or html data?

Comment: i want to send html as a pdf file, or here i don't want to edit anything in message body , atleast possible to disable keypad

Answer (score 2):

Sorry this is impossible, and violates of apple mail Compose-view, meaning your application could be denied for doing Non-editable email composer.

My only advice to you is to create a **custom email view controller** and implement this instead of using the Apple provided one.

other one also solution you send HTML code with calling **your Web service.**

for more detail:

[Third party framework Using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049270/how-to-customize-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-so-that-i-can-make-the-to-field-a)

[Lock MFMailComposeViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284599/locking-the-fields-in-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller)